# Aspectj : getting the @Pointcut details in @Aspect

Tags: aspectj

I have an aspect that is called for any of the pointcuts defined, similar to something like this:

```
@Around("pointcut1(request) || pointcut2(request) || pointcut3(request)")
public ModelAndView myAspect(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJp, 
                             HttpServletRequest request)
{
    //do something.
}
```

So inside this aspect, I need to know that for which pointcut (pointcut1/2/3) this myAspect is called. Is there any why I can get this in aspect?

To add more details .....

Isn't there any parameter that I can get in @Aspect (method). I know I can get JoinPoint , but it doesn't work well for me. 
Something like this would be very convenient....

```
@Around("pointcut1(request) || pointcut2(request) || pointcut3(request)")
public ModelAndView myAspect(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJp, PointCut pc ,HttpServletRequest request){
if (pc.equals("pointcut1")) {
    //do something.
}
if (pc.equals("pointcut2")) {
    //do something.
}
// ...
```

}

Please suggest !!

Any more suggestions please !!!

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to write advice for each of the component pointcuts and set a flag saying that it has been reached.  Due to Aspect precedence (ie- which advice runs before which other advice), you need to ensure that the component advice is lexically above the final around advice.  It will look like this:

```
boolean pointcut1Reached = false;

ModelAndView around(HttpServletRequest request) : pointcut1(request) {
    pointcut1Reached = true;
    try {
         proceed(request);
    } finally {
         pointcut1Reached = false;
    }
}

// ... similar for other pointcuts

@Around("pointcut1(request) || pointcut2(request) || pointcut3(request)")
public ModelAndView myAspect(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJp, HttpServletRequest request){
    if (pointcut1Reached) {
        //do something.
    }
    if (pointcut2Reached) {
        //do something.
    }
    // ...
}
```

Two things to note here:

1. If your program is multithreaded, then you are going to need to ensure that the instantiation of the aspect is appropriate.
2. I use code style AspectJ syntax because I have a personal bias against annotation style.  :)

---

To avoid the problems of multithreaded code, you can specify an instantiation model for the aspect.

```
aspect MyAspect percflowbelow( execution ( * * HttpServletRequest.something(..) ) { ... }
```

The statement above says that there will be one instance of the aspect instantiated for each cflow below a call to `HttpServletRequest.something()`.  If one of the advice is reached inside the aspect, but it is not in the percflowbelow, then the advice will not be run.

The only trick now is to figure out what kind of pointcut should be placed inside of `percflowbelow`.  Is there some method call way up in the stack that contains all of the pointcuts?

Once you have this figured out, you do not need to worry about multithreading.

Comment: Hi Andrew, Thanks for your suggestion. It looks good and will work for me, but also looks like it will be a bit heavy ( two around advice ) and as you pointed out , I would need to take care of multithreading. Isn't there any parameter that I can get in @Aspect (method). I know I can get JoinPoint , but it doesn't work well for me. Something like this would be very convenient. @Around("pointcut1(request) || pointcut2(request) || pointcut3(request)") public ModelAndView myAspect(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJp, PointCut pc ,HttpServletRequest request){

Comment: Well, if you go with code style aspectj, you don't need to worry about multi-threading.  You can specify an instantiation model in the aspect.  I'll edit the question to show you how.